# Какое правило для тире в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> По-настоящему она была дочь мелкого мещанина — простая, грубая женщина в грязной кацавейке (В. Набоков. Отчаяние).

Какое правило для тире в этом предложении?

Answer (score 1):

*По-настоящему она была дочь мелкого мещанина – **простая, грубая женщина в грязной кацавейке.***

Здесь действуют несколько правил, например:

1) Если определяемым словом является **личное местоимение**, то приложение обособляется всегда. Если приложение находится **на расстоянии** от определяемого слова, то оно тоже всегда обособляется.

Но по этим правилам приложение **обособляется в общем случае (запятой или тире).**

2)  При обособлении приложений вместо запятой **употребляется тире:**

— перед распространенным или одиночным приложением, стоящим в конце предложения, если подчеркивается самостоятельность приложения либо дается разъяснение: Объехали какую-то старую плотину, потонувшую в крапиве, и давно высохший **пруд — глубокую яругу, заросшую бурьяном** (Бун.);

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

По этому правилу для обособления используется **тире, а не запятая.** Тире обозначает увеличенную паузу. Наличие собственных знаков препинания способствует обособлению с помощью тире.

Comment: И ещё. Если видеть одну картинку - то это психическая стабильность, хоть и в этом проявляется стандартность (видеть только один вариант из нескольких). А у креативных людей наоборот - часто меняется настроение без причины или поведение, повышенная эмоциональность - нет психической стабильности. В этом плане оно "не совсем хорошо" для психики. Смотря под каким углом посмотреть.

Comment: Я отвечу вам позже по возможности, сейчас нет времени. Желаю успехов в работе на форуме.

Comment: Почему это работа? За работу деньги платят. Это должно быть отдыхом или хобби (для кого русский - специальность). Я не планирую больше отвечать, ну может изредка на что-то очень интересное. На это очень много времени уходит. На некоторые ответы - больше часа. А потом ещё целый день вспоминаю и думаю, что можно улучшить. Было такое, что и часа 4 размышлял над вопросом. || Согласно официальному названию это не форум, а "Сайт вопросов и ответов для лингвистов и энтузиастов русского языка". На форумах нет лимитов - запрещают много коммент. макс 600 символов, чётко вопрос - ответ, и ничего больше.

Comment: Не хотите работать? Тогда получайте удовольствие от того, чем вы занимаетесь. Этот форум может дать многое в области изучения языка: вопросов большое количество, мнения высказываются разные. Решайте интересные для вас задачи, смотрите, как их решили другие. Но в то же время  будьте осторожны. Это структура, а общение с системой небезопасно. Она тоже постарается использовать вас по полной, забрать всё ваше  время.  Для этого у нее есть возможности: соревновательная система, например, которая "затягивает", привыкание опять же возникает. На спорный вопрос, о котором вы говорили, я отвечу.

Comment: В. Е.  хотел вам заплатить, но ему не позволили https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/469/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2 Такой книги у Розенталя я не знаю. У него есть Справочник по пунктуации и Трудные случаи грамматики и правописания (Добромыслов и Розенталь).

Comment: И не могли позволить. Для изменений нужно обращаться в эту ветку (на английском): https://meta.stackexchange.com Хотел заплатить вам в первую очередь (28 июня меня здесь ещё не было) — вы гораздо больше отвечали. Честно говоря, мне нравятся его вопросы — как языковая математика. Для этого не нужно менять сайт, можно просто взять номер карты или т.п. Это обычный донат. || Это очень крутая книга: https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=cFvwwAEACAAJ&dq Можем удалить старые комментарии, чтобы их в чат не перекинули. Мне там тоже очень неуютно: он изолирован от основного сайта.

Comment: Ещё тут есть интересный вопрос. Не могу понять: с одной стороны да, а с другой - нет. Кроме вас, здесь никто не в состоянии ответить: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/456346/Они-писали-о-чем-хотели